# Azure Function Error There is no current event loop in thread

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-data-explorer

I have a python Azure function that has been running for months.  On 7/23 it started failing with the error There is no current event loop in thread.

I'll post the relevant bits of code:

In the **init**.py I create a JSON event and then have the call:
'''

```
run_func(event)
```

'''

The run_func function looks like:
'''

```
def run_func(event):
    print("Running Start")
    query = "Sites "              
    client = KustoClient(kcsb)
```

'''

The failure is on the last line shown above.  I have updated the azure.kusto.data package to the latest version.  It fails every time with the same error.

I'll post the full error here:

2021-07-30T00:00:42.188890984Z  ---> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Workers.Rpc.RpcException: Result: Failure
2021-07-30T00:00:42.188893884Z Exception: RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0'.
2021-07-30T00:00:42.188896584Z Stack:   File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.8/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 398, in _handle__invocation_request
2021-07-30T00:00:42.188899484Z     call_result = await self._loop.run_in_executor(
2021-07-30T00:00:42.188901784Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 57, in run
2021-07-30T00:00:42.188904284Z     result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
2021-07-30T00:00:42.188906784Z   File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.8/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 602, in _run_sync_func
2021-07-30T00:00:42.188910284Z     return ExtensionManager.get_sync_invocation_wrapper(context,
2021-07-30T00:00:42.188913984Z   File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.8/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/extension.py", line 215, in _raw_invocation_wrapper
2021-07-30T00:00:42.188918084Z     result = function(**args)
2021-07-30T00:00:42.188921384Z   File "/home/site/wwwroot/TimerTrigger1/**init**.py", line 24, in main
2021-07-30T00:00:42.188924985Z     run_func(event)
2021-07-30T00:00:42.188928585Z   File "/home/site/wwwroot/TimerTrigger1/soofie_azure.py", line 1281, in run_func
2021-07-30T00:00:42.188931185Z     client = KustoClient(kcsb)
2021-07-30T00:00:42.188944585Z   File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/azure/kusto/data/client.py", line 763, in **init**
2021-07-30T00:00:42.188948785Z     self._auth_provider = _AadHelper(self._kcsb) if self._kcsb.aad_federated_security else None
2021-07-30T00:00:42.188953185Z   File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/azure/kusto/data/security.py", line 23, in **init**
2021-07-30T00:00:42.188955785Z     self.token_provider = ApplicationKeyTokenProvider(self.kusto_uri, kcsb.authority_id, kcsb.application_client_id, kcsb.application_key)
2021-07-30T00:00:42.188958385Z   File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/azure/kusto/data/_token_providers.py", line 485, in **init**
2021-07-30T00:00:42.188960885Z     super().**init**(kusto_uri)
2021-07-30T00:00:42.188963685Z   File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/azure/kusto/data/_token_providers.py", line 69, in **init**
2021-07-30T00:00:42.188966285Z     self._async_lock = asyncio.Lock()
2021-07-30T00:00:42.188968585Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/asyncio/locks.py", line 164, in **init**
2021-07-30T00:00:42.188971485Z     self._loop = events.get_event_loop()
2021-07-30T00:00:42.188974985Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/asyncio/events.py", line 639, in get_event_loop
2021-07-30T00:00:42.188978885Z     raise RuntimeError('There is no current event loop in thread %r.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This a a known bug in version 2.3.0

2.3.1 will be released soon with a fix, meanwhile as a workaround you can use 2.2.1

Comment: Thank you a million times!  Can't tell you how many hours I squandered trying to figure that out!